# storing multiple checkboxes value in a variable or array

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

so this works fine

HTML

```
<p></p>
<select id="single">
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>Single2</option>
</select> 
<select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
</select>

<div>
    <span class="label">Hobbies</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" id="hel" value="hel">
    <label for="hel">hel</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" id="pickle" value="pickle">
    <label for="pickle">Pickle eating</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" id="walnut" value="walnut">
    <label for="walnut">Making walnut butter</label>
</div>

function displayVals() {
var singleValues = $( "#single" ).val();
var multipleValues = $( "#multiple" ).val() || [];
$( "p" ).html( "<b>Single:</b> " + singleValues +
    " <b>Multiple:</b> " + multipleValues.join( ", " ) );}

$( "select" ).change( displayVals );
displayVals();
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/bfha4881/

but when I change the JQuery Selector to input it returs
multipleValues.join() is not a function!

```
function displayVals() {
var singleValues = $( "#single" ).val();
var multipleValues = $( "input[name='hobby']:checked" ).val() || [];
$( "p" ).html( "<b>Single:</b> " + singleValues +
    " <b>Multiple:</b> " + multipleValues.join( ", " ) );
}

$( "input" ).change( displayVals );
displayVals();
```

so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For input elements, the returned value will be string, so for array of checkboxes you can iterate over checked inputs and then use [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map) to create an array as below

```
function displayVals() {
    var singleValues = $("#single").val();
    var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || [];
    var hobbies = $('input[name="hobby"]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    $("p").html("<b>Single:</b> " + singleValues +
        " <b>Multiple:</b> " + multipleValues.join(", ") +
        " <b>Hobies:</b> " + hobbies.join(", "));
}

$("select, input").change(displayVals);
displayVals();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qnvcrwbc/)

Comment: can you please explain the last part of this:  var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || [];
does the: .val()|| [] indicates single or multiple value?

Comment: @Sam-Gh. if the select element is a multi select then `.val()` will return an array of selected values.. but if no values is selected then `null` is returned so `|| []` used to return an empty array if there are no elements selected

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var values = [];    
$( "input[name='hobby']:checked" ).each(function(){
    values.push($(this).val());
});
var str = values.join(", ");
```

Also, you can concatenate directly in the "each", but remember to remove the ", " from the last loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get **all** checkboxes, you can do that with `.each()` function...

```
var checkBoxes = "";
function displayVals() {
  var singleValues = $( "#single" ).val();
  $( "input[name='hobby']:checked" ).each(function() {
        checkBoxes += $(this).val() + " ";
    });

  $( "p" ).html( "<b>Single:</b> " + singleValues +
    " <b>Multiple:</b> " + checkBoxes );
    checkBoxes = "";
}
```

Here is working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfha4881/2/)